# how to insert data to bootstrap table from redux store in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have data (array) in redux store. I have created actions and reducer for it but how can I display data that is already stored in redux store to my bootstrap table ?

my functional component that has table :

```
const Contacts = function () {

 
    return (
        <div>
        <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

my redux store:

> import {createStore} from 'redux' import {composeWithDevTools} from
> 'redux-devtools-extension'
>
> const initialState = {
>
> ```
> contacts:[
>
>     {
>         "id": 1,
>         "name": "Leanne Graham",
>         "username": "Bret",
>         "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
>         "address": {
>           "street": "Kulas Light",
>           "suite": "Apt. 556",
>           "city": "Gwenborough",
>           "zipcode": "92998-3874",
>           "geo": {
>             "lat": "-37.3159",
>             "lng": "81.1496"
>           }
>         },
>         "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
>         "website": "hildegard.org",
>         "company": {
>           "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
>           "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
>           "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 2,
>         "name": "Ervin Howell",
>         "username": "Antonette",
>         "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
>         "address": {
>           "street": "Victor Plains",
>           "suite": "Suite 879",
>           "city": "Wisokyburgh",
>           "zipcode": "90566-7771",
>           "geo": {
>             "lat": "-43.9509",
>             "lng": "-34.4618"
>           }
>         },
>         "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
>         "website": "anastasia.net",
>         "company": {
>           "name": "Deckow-Crist",
>           "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
>           "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 3,
>         "name": "Clementine Bauch",
>         "username": "Samantha",
>         "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
>         "address": {
>           "street": "Douglas Extension",
>           "suite": "Suite 847",
>           "city": "McKenziehaven",
>           "zipcode": "59590-4157",
>           "geo": {
>             "lat": "-68.6102",
>             "lng": "-47.0653"
>           }
>         },
>         "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
>         "website": "ramiro.info",
>         "company": {
>           "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
>           "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
>           "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 4,
>         "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
>         "username": "Karianne",
>         "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
>         "address": {
>           "street": "Hoeger Mall",
>           "suite": "Apt. 692",
>           "city": "South Elvis",
>           "zipcode": "53919-4257",
>           "geo": {
>             "lat": "29.4572",
>             "lng": "-164.2990"
>           }
>         },
>         "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
>         "website": "kale.biz",
>         "company": {
>           "name": "Robel-Corkery",
>           "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
>           "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
>         }
>       }
>
>
> ] }
>
>
>        const contactReducer =(state=initialState,action)=> {
>        switch(action.type){
>
>       default:
> return state;
>
>        }
>
>        }
>
>      const store=createStore(contactReducer,composeWithDevTools())
>
>       export default store;
> ```

Comment: loop your data with jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `react-redux` and get the state. You can check the example [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'


const Contacts = function () {
     //choose your reducer from store
     const data = useSelector(state => state.yourReducerName)

     //data for use
     <tbody>
         {data.map(contact => (
            <tr>
             <th scope="row">{contact.id}</th>
             <td>{contact.name}</td>
             <td>{contact.username}</td>
             <td>{contact.email}</td>
            </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
}
```

Comment: and then how do i insert that data into rows and columns ?

Comment: @TipsandTricksOfChess I have updated the answer. The trick is you need to select your own reducer in the ```useSelector``` function. Then you can use the ```map``` function to loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in redux store you can use like this:

```
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    const Contacts = function ({contacts}) {

 
    return (
        <div>
        <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {contacts.map(element => (
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{element.id}</th>
            <td>{element.name}</td>
            <td>{element.username}</td>
            <td>{element.email}</td>
          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
    
      </table>
        </div>
    )
   }

   function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
       contacts: state.contacts //get store data 
    };
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AccountMenu)
```

Comment: tsecheukfung01 is saying to use hooks .... hooks allow you to subscribe to the Redux store and dispatch actions, without having to wrap your components in connect().